# Preciseness of DRY Principle

Tags: html, css, dry

I've been diving into html/css over the past few weeks and am now trying to optimize my code with the DRY principle (along with SMACSS/OOCSS/BEM). I believe I have a decent understanding of it all, but there's one thing that's still unclear to me.

Should the DRY principle be applied 100% of the time? Let's say, for example, you have 'text-transform: uppercase;' being applied to two different classes. According to the DRY principle, you'd remove the rule set from each individual class and place it under a comma-separated list of both classes. But after awhile, doesn't this make your stylesheet a complete mess, where every class is being declared multiple times on the same sheet? Or does it really not matter what your sheet looks like, since you could simply search for "uppercase" in the search box if any future changes were needed?

It seems that you wouldn't be getting any performance improvements out of this scenario. Yes, you'd be removing one property from your sheet, but you'd also be adding an entirely new rule set and repeating the class name.

I understand it could be done either way depending on preference and each project, but I'm more concerned with what might be the most efficient way (especially when it comes to building large, complex sites). I'd like to stay consistent throughout all of my projects moving forward.

Are there any sort of guidelines to go off of? For example, maybe only combining duplicate code if the amount of properties you're removing is greater than X? Or only combining duplicate code when they're related semantically?

Comment: Probably best asked at [programmers.se] instead.

Comment: In 2015, it will be very hard to find a device that would struggle with CSS (without abusing transforms/transitions/shadows) no matter how you write it, so you shouldn't worry much about performance as much as code maintability.

Comment: A CSS preprocessor such as LESS or SASS will help to give you DRY without sacrificing maintainability. On the DRY rule specifically, I'd say that it applies when two classes will ALWAYS vary together. In the uppercase example, if you have a theme in which certain headings are uppercase, then DRY makes sense. If each heading could be uppercase or lowercase, then DRY doesn't make sense since they vary independently in concept.

Comment: My opinion: http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#groupstyles _"One caveat to this is that you should not attempt to eradicate all occurrences of style duplication. When two elements happen to share the same color or font size as a consequence of a design decision that has nothing to do with the meaning of those elements, then it is possible that they may later want to have different colors, sizes, etc. While it is not difficult to later split a compound selector into its components, you may save yourself some work by not overzealously merging every style/value pair."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programmers who read your code after will thank you if you optimize for maintainability, not strict adherence to any particular dogma.

Please don't misunderstand. DRY is important, but you should temper it (or any other design pattern) with a variation on the simple sanity check: "Does this make sense?". In the case of DRY, this would be something along the lines of "Are these actually related?".

If the answer is "yes", strongly implying that if one of the classes were to drop the `text-transform:uppercase;` the other would also, then by all mean extract it out.

If the answer is "no", then you'd actually be making it more difficult to maintain later because you'd need to undo the artificial coupling between the two classes.

In this case, simply having a laundry-list of the classes that use a particular attribute is fake DRY, because you are definitely repeating yourself. The repetition has simply moved from the attribute to the class.

Answer (score 0):

The DRY principle is all about **"not repeating yourself"**.
If it's just you that's going to work on the same file, then I suggest to code in a way that is understandable (clean enough) for you, so you can easily edit it when you need to. But if others are going to work on it as well, it's even more important you keep it as clean and DRY.

You could argue that applying the DRY principle isn't really necessary, since you can repeat yourself and the code will still work. But then you could argue, why use Sass (which is a compiler and can make your css even shorter), and you could argue why compress your css file (so the website loads faster) because without it, it will still work!

My advice is to ALWAYS consider keeping it DRY and clean as possible. In your example you're pointing out to a small detail, and the DRY method won't make a big difference when you clean your CSS and you realise you've only saved 2 extra lines of CSS. But what if you apply it when you have 10.000 lines of CSS?

It makes you define a property only ONCE. And if you need an example of how important and how much lines of code it can save you, check this out: http://www.slideshare.net/jeremyclarke/dry-css-a-dontrepeatyourself-methodology-for-creating-efficient-unified-and-scalable-stylesheets

In the long run it will keep your stylesheet much cleaner, more understandable for you and others and much easier to edit! 
So I'd say it's pretty important and if you can drill it in from the beginning you'll be very thankful later :)

Answer (score 0):

> Should the DRY principle be applied 100% of the time?

No, it's not intended to be.

DRY is for managing the canonical source of information. DRY is for avoiding the problem of "this information appears twice but isn't the same - which is correct?".

There is no difference from a DRY between:

```
.foo { text-transform: uppercase; color: red  } 
.bar { text-transform: uppercase; color: blue }
```

and

```
.foo { color: red  } 
.bar { color: blue } 
.foo, bar { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

because `text-transform: uppercase` is in effect a single unit of information. The point of DRY is not to make coders replicate a compression algorithm by refactoring out repeated strings, but to identify places where the same semantic relationship is being expressed multiple times.

It might be worth using the latter rule if `.foo` and `.bar` are both used for a role which demands uppercase, because you might want to change both at the same time. But if they are used for two different things which both happen to require uppercase then use the former rule because there is no reason why a change to one would necessitate a change to the latter.

With this particular example and CSS more generally, it's all much of a muchness.